# How would a database structure for a quiz look like?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here's how my current quiz database structure looks like:

For the sake of testing and simplicity, I've put up only 3 questions.
This is how my table (quiz) looks like:

```
| id | score | q1_answered | q2_answered | q3_answered |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 210   |      0      |       1     |      0      |
| 9  | 380   |      1      |       0     |      1      |
| 5  | 210   |      1      |       1     |      1      |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Each question column has numbers from 0 to 1, **0** indicating is hasn't been answered and **1** indicating it has been answered correctly.

I was wondering if any of you have another idea of creating a better structure or better, efficient.
Is there also an efficient way to add a timestamp for a user who has solved a specific question?

Say for example: If a user answers question 1, the time of answer will be recorded and will be displayed.

This structure could work but I always thought it might not be efficient if I were to add say 50 more questions.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create two tables based on the table you have:

```
scores
sID score testID
1   210    1
9   380    1
// etc etc

quests
sID testID question answer anstime
1      1    1         0     1231237128961
1      1    2         1     1231237128964
1      1    3         0     1231237128968
9      1    1         1     1231237128961
9      1    2         0     1231237128968
```

Basically, you are normalizing your data in a way that you can easily add more questions without the need to modify the table in any way, you still have a nice clean table where you keep scores that is easy to join

You can also then do much more interesting queries, like How many people answered question 3 at a certain time, aggregate the data nicely and of course, still join it back to the scores if you want to display all the results for a particular ID.

I have also added two columns in the tables called testID. This way, you are able to track not only multiple users for one test, but multiple users across multiple test. you will be able to see whether a student is improving over the course of tests or progressively getting worse as the subject carries on.

Edit: To copy data from your structure will be a bit annoying, but this should get you started on the path at least:

```
insert into quests (sID, question, answer)
select sID, testID, q1_answered from yourTableName
```

You can insert the data into the new structure by using a select statement on your original tables like I showed you above.

Comment: Thanks for advice. However, how would you go about transferring/copying the "id" column from the "scores" table to the "quests" table?

Comment: For completion, shouldn't there be a discrete PK in both tables, or a quick explanation that multiple columns can be used as PKs?

Comment: @MaxWayne Do you mean how would you copy your current data into the new structure?

Comment: @ChrisW Possibly, but where do you draw the line? After keys, should we discuss indexes, possible partitioning methods and so on and so on? While I would love to have the time to answer each question like this with enough detail to fill a small book, giving them the perfect answer, sometimes I think it is up to the user to have a little initiative.

Comment: Yes, I agree - I got the impression the questioner might not have much knowledge about RDBSs, and I've always followed the philosophy of 'linked tables must always have PKs / FKs, for data compliance, before thinking about anything else'

Comment: @Fluffeh Yea, like how do I link "id" columns between "scores" table and "quests" table? Say for example in my "scores" table, I have the "id" column. If I were to create "quests" table, how would I go about adding the same "id" column from "scores" table?

Comment: @MaxWayne I have made an edit which gave an example of code that you could use to migrate your data from one to the other. It will however be a painful process I think.

Comment: @Fluffeh Thanks a lot for the addition Fluffeh. It would be a bit annoying due to the fact I'll have to find a way to migrate new data as new users register. Nonetheless though, I shall perform more researches and figure a solution. Your post pretty much answers my question. Thanks again. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you define one table for the questions and one for the answers given by users:

Questions:
QuestionID, QuestionName, ...

Answers:
AnswerID, UserID, QuestionID, AnswerGiven, AnswerCorrect, DateAnswered

This way if you add a new question, you don't have to change the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about efficiency with 50 questions.  Just have some fun programming.  Try things out.  If you have a million questions, or hundreds of thousands of questions you might start to think about efficiency.  Computers are really fast.